# Reference to shared folder lost after first run

Tags: vba, error-handling, outlook, move, shared-directory

I want to move an email from a shared inbox to a shared subfolder in the same inbox.

I have two mailboxes and the shared one is the second.

"Outbound TTA" = the name of the second shared mailbox.

"réception" = the name of the Inbox folder in the "Outbound TTA"

"MyFolderEmails" = the name of the subfolder in the "réception" folder.

The code works **only once**!

The second time it shows

> Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)':The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.

The error appears at `Set sharedDestinationFolder = sharedInbox.Folders("MyFolderEmails")`

```vb
Public Sub test2()
    MoveSelectionToFolder
End Sub


Private Sub MoveSelectionToFolder()
    Dim NS As nameSpace

    Dim sharedInbox As folder
    Dim sharedDestinationFolder As folder

    Dim sharedItems As Selection

    Dim i As Long

    Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set sharedInbox = NS.Folders("Outbound TTA").Folders("réception")
    Set sharedDestinationFolder = sharedInbox.Folders("MyFolderEmails")
        
    Set sharedItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    For i = sharedItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        sharedItems(i).Move sharedDestinationFolder
    Next i

    Set NS = Nothing
    Set sharedItems = Nothing
    Set sharedInbox = Nothing
    Set sharedDestinationFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, even similar codes have the same fate, work only once; after that they show the error.

Comment: This is very puzzling. Your code doesn't seem to have any problems. Try adding this condition in the loop `If TypeName(sharedItems(i)) = "MailItem" Then` before you move the item. Also, you say "first" and "second" time, when does it become "first" time again? I mean when does it work again? Is it when you quit outlook and start it again? I am just thinking that there might be something you can reset at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Yes, it works again after I close and start the Outlook again. Yes, the reset is the solution. But to reset what ?. I am on this problem for a week and can't get past this point. Works once and the error after. The thing is that it does not "see" any subfolder in the "réception" inbox (the code I mean). This problem is the same on another computer of a coleg of mine. So the outlook works perfectly fine ...

Comment: Try to refresh your inbox by adding this line `NS.Logon "", "", False, True` after `Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")`. Got it from https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/refresh-outlook-inbox-via-vba.291386/

Comment: I did exactly that and the behavior is the same: works once and no more after that (it gives the same error as above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try to preserve the reference to the folder as a static variable like this. (restart your outlook and then use the code)

```
' Set it as a static variable
Global sharedDestinationFolder As Folder

Public Sub test2()
    MoveSelectionToFolder
End Sub


Private Sub MoveSelectionToFolder()
    Dim NS As Namespace

    Dim sharedInbox As Folder
    'Dim sharedDestinationFolder As Folder

    Dim sharedItems As Selection

    Dim i As Long
       
    If sharedDestinationFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set sharedInbox = NS.Folders("Outbound TTA").Folders("réception")
        Set sharedDestinationFolder = sharedInbox.Folders("MyFolderEmails")
        
        MsgBox "Setting destination folder"
    End If
        
    Set sharedItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    For i = sharedItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        If TypeName(sharedItems(i)) = "MailItem" Then
            sharedItems(i).Move sharedDestinationFolder
        End If
    Next i

    Set NS = Nothing
    Set sharedItems = Nothing
    Set sharedInbox = Nothing
    'Set sharedDestinationFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

In theory, the first time you run the code you will see the message box. When you run it again, it won't be `Nothing` and therefore, it should have a valid reference to the correct folder (again in theory)

Comment: First run: all ok. The message box says: Setting destination folder, and the mails are moved as planned. Second time: the error appears. Note: it is like the sharedDestinationFolder is nothing the second time ...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. try again. I forgot to remove the last line. Remember you're setting `sharedDestinationFolder` to `Nothing` by hand.

Comment: CAN I SAY I LOVE YOU ? IT WORKS ! :)

Comment: You can, but now I have to hide the comuter from my wife :) Glad it worked

Comment: Kindly don't forget to accept the answer, and if you have any further problems regarding this issue, just update this post. Thanks

Comment: :)) this is extraordinary. This is the solution for many that had the very same question. I am an experienced programmer but I simply could not find a solution for this one. It is also the very first time I am helped by another programmer in the wild :) Thank you very, very much for your time. I promise to to the same with somebody in need :)